# SER cable mounting requirements

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Just wondering if the 2-2-2-4 SER is required to be secured to the wall here? I'm going to screw a piece of plywood to the wall and secure the cable to it regardless. Also, as I'm sure some of y'all will notice it, I did add a bushing to the cable clamp after taking the pic. [image]

Comment: A bonded panel, green screw in evidence, yet the "OCD chop all the wires as short as possible" worker felt the need to make one bus ground and the other neutral...An odd choice.

Comment: Should this ever become a subpanel, @Ecnerwal, that'll make things easier, no?

Comment: NO! The "ground bar" as wired is the other isolated neutral bar. If the bonding screw is removed, it's not attached to the case, and every wire on it needs to be moved to a grounding bar that IS attached to the case. If you wanted to "make things easier for future sub-panelization" or "keep ground and neutral separated except for the bonding screw" spend $15 or so on some accessory ground bars. Get 2, put one on each side, make the wiring a lot less absurd. This is a form of "tidy OCD" that actually makes many things harder (like AFCI/GFCI breakers)

Comment: Those cables coming down the wall need physical protection below a certain height like 6'6" or something.  There's a reason the builder went in the top. For the connection to the electrician's outlet, feel free to use an EMT conduit nipple; that's the way that is usually done.

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need plywood if you are willing to use appropriate concrete screws *(which you'll need to put the plywood on, and at the price of plywood these days....)* and cable clamps; but both that 10 gauge cable and the new SE cable should be attached to the wall, yes. Example, not endorsment:

[image: Cable clamp image from topaz-usa no endorsment implied]

For that matter the 14Ga cable powering the network should be, too.

Within 12" of the clamp on the box. *(8" for boxes without clamps.)*

If the network power is less than 2 feet to the box, one clamp in the middle would suit the lower section. Or you might be able to use a couple of staples into the router mounting board. It will need another clamp within 12" of where it goes out the top of that box.

I don't think you have enough additional distance (54") to *require* another clamp on the 10 Ga and SE before the ceiling. But you can put some there if you like. Code is a minimum.

Comment: That area of the basement see's very minimal traffic......but I will be rearranging things this Spring, so I'll definitely secure all the cables to the wall as you suggested and then some just in case something does inadvertently snag a cable

Comment: Code applies regardless of the amount of traffic, except where code interpretation is that things are "exposed to damage" and it applies higher protection standards. The clamps are a minimum requirement.

Comment: I understand code is required and not based on my opinion. I was just adding anecdotal info about securing the cables with more than is required by code. Also the OCD wire chopper was me :) I've had several ppl tell me that I should have left extra wire just in case I needed to move a circuit, and they are right. But I am going to rewire the house soon so that will be rectified then.